# Aggregate a dataframe on a given column and display another column

Tags: r, aggregate, plyr, greatest-n-per-group

I have a dataframe in R of the following form:

```
> head(data)
  Group Score Info
1     1     1    a
2     1     2    b
3     1     3    c
4     2     4    d
5     2     3    e
6     2     1    f
```

I would like to aggregate it following the `Score` column using the `max` function

```
> aggregate(data$Score, list(data$Group), max)

  Group.1         x
1       1         3
2       2         4
```

But I also would like to display the `Info` column associated to the maximum value of the `Score` column for each group. I have no idea how to do this. My desired output would be:

```
  Group.1         x        y
1       1         3        c
2       2         4        d
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

First, you split the data using `split`:

```
split(z,z$Group)
```

Than, for each chunk, select the row with max Score:

```
lapply(split(z,z$Group),function(chunk) chunk[which.max(chunk$Score),])
```

Finally reduce back to a data.frame `do.call`ing `rbind`:

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(split(z,z$Group),function(chunk) chunk[which.max(chunk$Score),]))
```

Result:

```
  Group Score Info
1     1     3    c
2     2     4    d
```

One line, no magic spells, fast, result has good names =)

Answer (score 55):

A base R solution is to combine the output of `aggregate()` with a `merge()` step. I find the formula interface to `aggregate()` a little more useful than the standard interface, partly because the names on the output are nicer, so I'll use that:

The `aggregate()` step is

```
maxs <- aggregate(Score ~ Group, data = dat, FUN = max)
```

and the `merge()` step is simply

```
merge(maxs, dat)
```

This gives us the desired output:

```
R> maxs <- aggregate(Score ~ Group, data = dat, FUN = max)
R> merge(maxs, dat)
  Group Score Info
1     1     3    c
2     2     4    d
```

You could, of course, stick this into a one-liner (the intermediary step was more for exposition):

```
merge(aggregate(Score ~ Group, data = dat, FUN = max), dat)
```

The main reason I used the formula interface is that it returns a data frame with the correct `names` for the merge step; these are the names of the columns from the original data set `dat`. We need to have the output of `aggregate()` have the correct names so that `merge()` knows which columns in the original and aggregated data frames match.

The standard interface gives odd names, whichever way you call it:

```
R> aggregate(dat$Score, list(dat$Group), max)
  Group.1 x
1       1 3
2       2 4
R> with(dat, aggregate(Score, list(Group), max))
  Group.1 x
1       1 3
2       2 4
```

We can use `merge()` on those outputs, but we need to do more work telling R which columns match up.

Comment: This is nice.  I played around with base R, but couldn't think of the solution.  It never crossed my mind to use `merge`.

Comment: Too early for me to think of such a neat answer.

Comment: @Roman Just one of the many benefits to having a 4 month-old I guess - even the shorter sleep time has its up-side ;-)

Comment: Does `merge` also work reliably when `Score` is float/double? IIRC, "equality" is not trivial with floats.

Comment: Both this and the accepted answer solved my problem.  This one is a little bit cleaner though, IMO.

Comment: If there is more than one item with max score, this solution returns both.  The `which.max` solution only returns one.

Comment: @Mohan right, but it'll do so in a way the depends on the order of the data. (And I'm aware of this; I said as much in my comment on Andrie's answer)

Comment: @GavinSimpson Not a criticism -- just useful in different situations. I ended up with a bug due to misunderstanding behaviour of one of the two solutions.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a solution using the `plyr` package.

The following line of code essentially tells `ddply` to first group your data by Group, and then within each group returns a subset where the Score equals the maximum score in that group.

```
library(plyr)
ddply(data, .(Group), function(x)x[x$Score==max(x$Score), ])

  Group Score Info
1     1     3    c
2     2     4    d
```

And, as @SachaEpskamp points out, this can be further simplified to:

```
ddply(df, .(Group), function(x)x[which.max(x$Score), ])
```

(which also has the advantage that `which.max` will return multiple max lines, if there are any).

Comment: `which.max(x$Score)` could be used instead of `x$Score==max(x$Score)`. In this example this works well, and in general it is cleaner, but it doesn't always work as desired when there are several maximums (ties).

Answer (score 6):

To add to Gavin's answer: prior to the merge, it is possible to get aggregate to use proper names when not using the formula interface:

```
aggregate(data[,"score", drop=F], list(group=data$group), mean)
```

Answer (score 5):

The `plyr` package can be used for this. With the `ddply()` function you can split a data frame on one or more columns and apply a function and return a data frame, then with the `summarize()` function you can use the columns of the splitted data frame as variables to make the new data frame/;

```
dat <- read.table(textConnection('Group Score Info
1     1     1    a
2     1     2    b
3     1     3    c
4     2     4    d
5     2     3    e
6     2     1    f'))

library("plyr")

ddply(dat,.(Group),summarize,
    Max = max(Score),
    Info = Info[which.max(Score)])
  Group Max Info
1     1   3    c
2     2   4    d
```

Comment: Nice, but I think you'll agree my solution is slightly more general since it will return all columns in the original data.frame.

Comment: Yeah indeed. You could change `x$Score==max` in `which,max` if you assume that there is only one maximum per group.

Comment: Ah, that's nice.  I didn't know about `which.max`

Answer (score 5):

A late answer, but and approach using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(dat)

DT[, .SD[which.max(Score),], by = Group]
```

Or, if it is possible to have more than one equally highest score

```
DT[, .SD[which(Score == max(Score)),], by = Group]
```

Noting that (from `?data.table`

> `.SD` is a data.table containing the Subset of x's Data for each group, excluding the group column(s)

Comment: How can you calculate standard deviation only of the last six values, not of the whole column? Do you firstly need to aggregate the data or does there exist something like SQL-style `OVER (PARTITION ... BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` in R? I am trying to answer this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43629806/r-variances-of-the-last-6-months-6-months-by-count-and-by-date-range-with-sql-s) but stuck.

Comment: @hhh this looks like rolling sd, please upvote https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2778

Answer (score 4):

This is how I `base`ically think of the problem.

```
my.df <- data.frame(group = rep(c(1,2), each = 3), 
        score = runif(6), info = letters[1:6])
my.agg <- with(my.df, aggregate(score, list(group), max))
my.df.split <- with(my.df, split(x = my.df, f = group))
my.agg$info <- unlist(lapply(my.df.split, FUN = function(x) {
            x[which(x$score == max(x$score)), "info"]
        }))

> my.agg
  Group.1         x info
1       1 0.9344336    a
2       2 0.7699763    e
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't have a high enough reputation to comment on Gavin Simpson's answer, but I wanted to warn that there seems to be a difference in the default treatment of missing values between the standard syntax and the formula syntax for `aggregate`.

```
#Create some data with missing values 
a<-data.frame(day=rep(1,5),hour=c(1,2,3,3,4),val=c(1,NA,3,NA,5))
  day hour val
1   1    1   1
2   1    2  NA
3   1    3   3
4   1    3  NA
5   1    4   5

#Standard syntax
aggregate(a$val,by=list(day=a$day,hour=a$hour),mean,na.rm=T)
  day hour   x
1   1    1   1
2   1    2 NaN
3   1    3   3
4   1    4   5

#Formula syntax.  Note the index for hour 2 has been silently dropped.
aggregate(val ~ hour + day,data=a,mean,na.rm=T)
  hour day val
1    1   1   1
2    3   1   3
3    4   1   5
```