# Aggregate() - R - Is is possible to mask one of the aggregated columns from displaying and adding another column

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a "emp" dataset with name, grade and value(based on manager's feedback)

```
  name grade value
1  Ram     R   2.1
2  Sam     R   2.4
3  Jam     R   5.3
4 Bill     S   4.2
5 Claw     S   3.6
6  Men     S   1.2
7  Jay     P   5.3
8  Kay     P   3.8
9  Ray     P   3.2
```

With `aggregate(value ~ grade, data = emp, FUN=min)` I got the minimum value for each grade

```
  grade value
1     P   3.2
2     R   2.1
3     S   1.2
```

Based on the minimum value I wanted to display only the grade and the name but not the value column. Is this possible with `aggregate()` in R.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289538/aggregate-a-dataframe-on-a-given-column-and-display-another-column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible approach

```
library(data.table)
setDT(emp)[, .(name = name[which.min(value)]), by = grade]
#    grade name
# 1:     R  Ram
# 2:     S  Men
# 3:     P  Ray
```

Here's another

```
library(dplyr)
emp %>%
  group_by(grade) %>%
  summarise(name = name[which.min(value)])

# Source: local data table [3 x 2]
# 
#   grade name
# 1     R  Ram
# 2     S  Men
# 3     P  Ray
```

Or with base R

```
do.call(rbind, by(emp, emp$grade, 
                  function(x) data.frame(grade = as.character(x$grade[1L]), 
                                         name = x$name[which.min(x$value)])))
#   grade name
# P     P  Ray
# R     R  Ram
# S     S  Men
```

Comment: Your effort is appreciated, but my questions was is it not possible to use aggregate() function for doing the same?

Comment: I don't think so. Why would you insist on `aggregate`?

Comment: It's the wrong tool. `aggregate`'s functions only "see" a single vector at a time, so they don't have the necessary data to work on two columns. The base paradigm would be `lapply(split(,), FUN)`.