# How can you get all the minimum values of a variable by group?

Tags: r, data.table, minimum

I have a data frame:

```
df<-data.frame(P = c("A","A","A", "B","B","B", "C", "C", "C"), 
               index = c("ind1","ind2","ind3","ind1","ind2","ind3","ind1","ind2","ind3"),
               var = c(2,1,1,8,5,4,2,8,6))
```

I would like to get ALL the minimum valueS of `var` and their associated `index` for each values of `P`. 
I can do this:

```
DT <- data.table(df)
DT[  ,.SD[which.min(var)], by = P]
```

which gives only one minimum value of `var` (the first one) by `P`:

> ```
>    P index  var
> 1: A  ind2   1
> 2: B  ind3   4
> 3: C  ind1   2
> ```

And I would like:

> ```
>    P index  var
> 1: A  ind2   1
> 2: A  ind3   1
> 2: B  ind3   4
> 3: C  ind1   2
> ```

Ideas?

Comment: from my understanding, you want the minimum values for each unique pairing of index and P... However, how is it that your desired output has two observations for P == 'A'? Yet, at the same time, by that same rule, you only have unique observations for P values of 'B' and 'C'.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289538/aggregate-a-dataframe-on-a-given-column-and-display-another-column this should help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the help page for `which.min`, you'll note that it says:

> Determines the location, i.e., index of the (first) minimum or maximum of a numeric (or logical) vector.

If you wanted all values that match the minimum, you should try using `==`. Thus, continuing with your approach, try:

```
DT[, .SD[var == min(var)], by = P]
##    P index var
## 1: A  ind2   1
## 2: A  ind3   1
## 3: B  ind3   4
## 4: C  ind1   2
```

Answer (score 5):

Using dplyr, you could use one of the following:

```
library(dplyr)
DT %>% group_by(P) %>% filter(var == min(var))  # or %in% instead of ==
#Source: local data table [4 x 3]
#Groups: P
#
#       P  index   var
#  (fctr) (fctr) (dbl)
#1      A   ind2     1
#2      A   ind3     1
#3      B   ind3     4
#4      C   ind1     2
```

Or

```
DT %>% group_by(P) %>% top_n(1, desc(var)) # top_n() returns multiple rows in case of ties
#Source: local data table [4 x 3]
#Groups: P
#
#       P  index   var
#  (fctr) (fctr) (dbl)
#1      A   ind2     1
#2      A   ind3     1
#3      B   ind3     4
#4      C   ind1     2
```

Or

```
DT %>% group_by(P) %>% filter(min_rank(var) == 1)
#Source: local data table [4 x 3]
#Groups: P
#
#       P  index   var
#  (fctr) (fctr) (dbl)
#1      A   ind2     1
#2      A   ind3     1
#3      B   ind3     4
#4      C   ind1     2
```