# Extract the unique rows with maximum value in another column in R dataframe

Tags: r, greatest-n-per-group

I have this data frame called `mydf`. There are duplicated samples in the `Sample` column. I want to extract the unique sample rows with the maximum `total_reads` and get the `result`.

```
mydf<-structure(list(Sample = c("AOGC-02-0188", "AOGC-02-0191", "AOGC-02-0191", 
"AOGC-02-0191", "AOGC-02-0194", "AOGC-02-0194", "AOGC-02-0194"
), total_reads = c(27392583, 19206920, 34462563, 53669483, 24731988, 
43419826, 68151814), Lane = c("4", "5", "4", "4;5", "5", "4", 
"4;5")), .Names = c("Sample", "total_reads", "Lane"), row.names = c("166", 
"169", "170", "171", "173", "174", "175"), class = "data.frame")
```

result

```
  Sample        total_reads  Lane
 AOGC-02-0188    27392583    4
 AOGC-02-0191    53669483  4;5
 AOGC-02-0194    68151814  4;5
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aggregate a dataframe on a given column and display another column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289538/aggregate-a-dataframe-on-a-given-column-and-display-another-column)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `aggregate` and then `merge`,

```
merge(aggregate(total_reads ~ Sample, mydf, max), mydf)
#        Sample total_reads Lane
#1 AOGC-02-0188    27392583    4
#2 AOGC-02-0191    53669483  4;5
#3 AOGC-02-0194    68151814  4;5
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the `dplyr` package, you could do that like this:

```
mydf %>%
    group_by(Sample) %>% # for each unique sample
    arrange(-total_reads) %>% # order by total_reads DESC
    slice(1) # select the first row, i.e. with highest total_reads
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(mydf)`), grouped by "Sample", `order` the 'total_reads' desendingly and subset the first observation with `head`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydf)[order(-total_reads), head(.SD, 1) , Sample]
```