# Apply a maximum value to whole group

Tags: r, group-by, max

I have a df like this:

```
Id   count
1      0
1      5
1      7
2      5
2      10
3      2
3      5
3      4
```

and I want to get the maximum count and apply that to the whole "group" based on ID, like this:

```
Id   count   max_count
1      0        7
1      5        7
1      7        7
2      5        10
2      10       10
3      2        5
3      5        5
3      4        5
```

I've tried pmax, slice etc. I'm generally having trouble working with data that is in interval-specific form; if you could direct me to tools well-suited to that type of data, would really appreciate it!

Comment: I recommend trying the `tidyverse` package: `new_df <- df %>% group_by(Id) %>% mutate(maxcount = max(count))`

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out with help from Gavin Simpson here: [Aggregate a dataframe on a given column and display another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289538/aggregate-a-dataframe-on-a-given-column-and-display-another-column)

```
maxcount <- aggregate(count ~ Id, data = df, FUN = max)

new_df<-merge(df, maxcount)
```

---

Better way:

```
df$max_count <- with(df, ave(count, Id, FUN = max))
```